# How to get current logged user in Google app engine

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

i developing a application in spring framework  for get current user  in gmail  use

```
 UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
            User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
```

but when the user sign out with gmail and new user log in the code return old user .
how to clear spring chache.

Answer (score 2):

A Google App Engine App does not automatically track Gmail Login/Logout for user session. So signing out of gmail won't log user out of your app.

That said, Google Id can be used to sign in/out of your app. If you want your user to logout from your app, then [create a logout Url](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/UserService#createLogoutURL%28java.lang.String%29) and let user use that to logout.

Read more [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/#Java_Signing_in_and_out).

Comment: This is a good answer, but the OP mentions spring, so there is something else going on there.

Comment: The code that OP posted is clearly Google App Engine Api. Perhaps, OP thought the problem is because of some spring cache, but it doesn't look like to me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you wired spring security correctly in GAE,
you just need to do:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
```

...
...

```
UserDetails user = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                    .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```